"Exporting encrypted key failed" Facing this error in android studio while creating a signed bundle of an app made in kotlin
I am unable to export keystore and encrypted keys as I am facing error. "Exporting encrypted key failed" Facing this error in android studio while creating a signed bundle of an app made in kotlin.
I tried changing the location and folders to check if it works, tried in C drive, E and D drive, but nothing works.

After updating Android Studio to the latest version, I also encountered an issue with generating a signed APK with existing key.I tried many solutions, but none of them worked. Then, I downgraded to the previous version of Android Studio, and it worked.

Which version worked for you? I am now using HedgeHog.

Iguana 2023.2.1
